# Dispatcher is not coming on C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher, windows

I have a C# Windows Forms Application with a progress bar. I want to progress that dynamically based on some method status. I have that method in a separate class, and am creating a new thread for that method, with a delegate to pass the status of the method to the parent thread.

The same situation I am able solve in a WPF application using `progressbar.Dispatcher` but in a Windows Forms application there is no Dispatcher, even if I use the `System.Threading` namespace.

`progressbar.Dispatcher` seems to be available only in a WPF Application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In winforms you can use the ProgressBar.Invoke or ProgressBar.BeginInvoke to update the control from another thread.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Form application `BackgroundWorker` should fit perfectly for your task. In particular, it has `ReportProgress` method to send progress depending on your calculations and `ProgressChanged` to track changes from UI thread. See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for full details

Answer (score 4):

In WinForms the `Invoke/BeginInvoke` methods are directly on the control objects as you can see from the docs of [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). So you'd have `progressBar.BeginInvoke(...)` for example.